# Use Twitter Bootstrap LESS files with NPM, in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, apostrophe-cms

What is considered best practice if I want to use compile Bootstrap from LESS files in my Apostrophe project?

Is it better to install Bootstrap via NPM, or should I manually download Bootstrap and place the files in `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/`?

I have reviewed the documentation that I am aware of to try and figure this out. I am not finding any documentation about including CSS and JS assets which are located outside of the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

You can put those files in lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/css (and subdirectories thereof, if desired) and include the one that imports all of the others in your configuration for `apostrophe-assets`, exactly as described in the tutorials:

[Pushing assets to the browser](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/pushing-assets.html)

Or you can import it from a LESS file of your own that also imports your custom site-specific styles. That's really up to you.

Of course there is also nothing stopping you from adding assets directly to your `outerLayout.html` via `link` and `script` tags but if you want to take advantage of Apostrophe's minification process, follow the tutorial.

To be clear, any and all templates in Apostrophe can be overridden for your particular project WITHOUT modifying the node_modules/apostrophe folder in any way.

If a template exists at this path:

```
node_modules/apostrophe/lib/module/MODULE-NAME/views/TEMPLATE-NAME.html
```

Then just copy it here in *your project*:

```
lib/module/MODULE-NAME/views/TEMPLATE-NAME.html
```

And your version will be rendered instead.

You can use the Nunjucks `extends` keyword to extend templates that you invent yourself. You can also use cross-module syntax to extend templates that are in a different module:

```
{# Finds it in the apostrophe-templates module, your version first, #}
{# node_modules if that doesn't exist #}

{% extends "apostrophe-templates:layout.html" %}
```

Hope this clears things up a little better!

Comment: ok, thank you.

The way you are suggesting to implement it will cause me an extra step in moving  files from the project's node_modules folder into the apostrophe-assets/public folder, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Also, why can't I create extend my own template from the `lib` folder? Is there some kind of documentation available that  discusses the philosophy behind the Apostrophe architecture?

Comment: This got answered on the forum, but for anyone else reading here:

Comment: It is still unclear how to include css files. Do I have to supply apostrophe-assets with less files, or can I compile my own less files and give apostrophe the css file? The tutorials do not mention anything about css files.

Furthermore, can I put my css files in with my own module? If so, how do I include those css files? If my files are:

/lib
   /modules
     /my-module
        index.js
        /public
            /css
                my-styles.css

How do include my-styles.css in my TEMPLATE? Currently I am trying `self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'my-styles', {when: 'always'});`

Comment: CSS is valid LESS (LESS is a superset of CSS). Have you tried to push your files? Does something go wrong?

Comment: You may need to give the file a .less extension.

Comment: So now that I have played with Apostrophe, I understand much better how to extend Apostrophe. Part of my confusion was because I did not understand how NodeJS and Apostrophe looked for assets.

Also, if i added a CSS style in Apostrophe-Assets module, does it automatically get compiled into the master.css stylesheet? I think that is what it was doing. I was expecting a separate LINK tag for every stlesheet.

Comment: Right, it minifies them together, extra requests = slow sites in production.